# Best way to call Python class methods automatically upon instantiation

Tags: python, oop

I have a machine learning algorithm which involves a series of steps, such as cleaning data, preparing training data etc. Each step is stored in a separate method of a python class. I'm wondering what the best practice way to structure my class is so that the steps are automatically executed upon class instantiation.

Here's what I've done (the code is illustrative, but this approach works on the real algorithm). It feels a little clunky. Is there a more elegant way?

```
 class Kaggle():
    """
    An algorithm
    """

    def __init__( self ):
        self.bar = 1

    def step_one( self, some_text_data ):
        self.bar = 1 ** 2
        # Do some data cleaning
        # return processed data

    def step_two( self ):
        foo = step_one(baz)
        # do some more processing

    def step_three( self ):
        bar = step_two()
        # output results

    def run( self ):
        self.step_one()
        self.step_two()
        self.step_three()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    kaggle = Kaggle()
    kaggle.run()
```

Comment: Put them all in the `__init__` method

Comment: Your code looks pretty clean and self-explanatory to me.  Easy to read, very clear.  What's "clunky" about it?

Comment: @EwanMellor having to call the `run()` method manually.

Comment: @cs_stackX Personally I don't find that clunky.  Doing "real work" in an initializer tends to make the code surprising to the next guy who comes along.  It looks like a simple variable initialization, but it's not.  I think having an extra line that is something like kaggle.run_all_the_steps() is actually valuable in the long run.

Comment: What is `raw_review` parameter in function `step_one`, you dont seem to provide it when you call the function. So the code wouldn't actually run, but everyone gets the idea of what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Yeah, it's illustrative for the question. Will edit for clarity

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If your goal is for the object to be "automatically executed upon class instantiation", just put `self.run()` in `__init__`:

```
def __init__(self):
    self.bar = 1
    self.run()
```

As an aside, one should try to keep the `__init__` method lightweight and just use it to instantiate the object.  Although "clunky", your original Kaggle class is how I would design it (i.e. instantiate the object and then have a separate `run` method to run your pipeline).  I might rename `run` to `run_pipeline` for better readability, but everything else looks good to me.

Answer (score 3):

Put all the calls in your `__init__` method. Is this not what you wanted to achieve? You could add a flag with a default value, that allows you to not run the tests if you want.

```
def __init__( self, runtests=True ):
    self.bar = 1
    if runtests:
        self.step_one()
        self.step_two()
        self.step_three()
```

Comment: I like this approach. I think the accepted answer should be the most efficient (particularly as this is in a ML context) - is it faster to call the step methods in the init method, or in a separate method which is called in the init method (as in @Alexander's solution below)?

Comment: If could also want to run the test together after initialisation its probably best to call the run method in `__init__` to avoid duplication of what constitutes the full set of tests.

Answer (score 0):

I  was working with dataclasses and found this to work as well:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class MyClass:
    var1: str
    var2: str

    def __post_init__(self):
        self.func1()
        self.func2()

    def func1(self):
        print(self.var1)

    def func2(self):
        print(self.var2)

a = MyClass('Hello', 'World!')
Hello
World!
```